# bool conflict in if statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

```
public void SteamaccountGrab()
{
    if (Directory.Exists(steamaccountDir32))
    {
        string steamaccountDir = @"C:\Program Files\Steam\config";
    }
    else
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(steamaccountDir64))
        {
            string steamaccountDir = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config";
        }
        else 
        {
            bool steamisinstalled = false;
        }

    }
    if (steamisinstalled)
    { 

    }
}
```

btw, I already declared bool steamisinstalled as true

In this piece of code it gives me an error at 
    "if (steamisinstalled)"
saying steamisinstalled conflicts with the declaration I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and/or what i have to do to fix this. Any help would be very much apreciated!

Comment: Could you paste in the **actual** error? Even though I already know what it is... it's going to mention how steamisinstalled isn't in the local scope. And steamaccountDir will also if you try to use it in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `bool` from `bool steamisinstalled = false;` Since you say, you have already declared it.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring `bool steamisinstalled = false;` within the scope of `else`, and referencing it in an outer scope which is causing a conflict.

Move the declaration to an outer scope and that should resolve your error.